# Changing binlog_format in MariaDB slave

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-replication, master-slave, mariadb-10.3

I have mariadb 10.3 master and slave running in AWS EC2, whose binlog format is MIXED for both. I want to migrate this db to Aurora MySQL using DMS and understand DMS needs the format to be in ROW.

I also came across this statement in one of the stackoverflow thread -

> the setting of binlog_format on the slave does not specify what the slave expects. It only sets what the slave will generate.

Question 1) Can i change the binlog format in slave to "ROW" and enable "log_slave_updates", without touching master(MIXED) for DMS to work, considering slave is the source of DMS?

Question 2) If above is fine to do, does data replication from master (MIXED) to slave(ROW) will have any issues until DMS copy over the data from slave into Aurora MySql?